# JDT AST - is there a bug with methods after nested classes?

Tags: java-8, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to parse the `java` classes in order to populate my objects with data - using the [JDT AST](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FAST.html). Most of the time this works just fine. However, there seems to be an issue with the [`java.util.Locale`](https://pastebin.com/YAzHUg13) class.

While other classes get parsed as expected (to the best of my knowledge), the `java.util.Locale` fails when it comes to the methods directly after the [statically nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) `LanguageRange`.

Now, I borrowed some code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14293450/6656268) and modified it to suit my needs to quickly setup a test environment.

**Example**

```
public static void parse(String code) {
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setSource(code.toCharArray());
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration method) {
            if(method.getName().toString().equals("filter")){
                debug("method", method.getName().getFullyQualifiedName());
                if(method.getParent().getNodeType() == ASTNode.TYPE_DECLARATION){
                    TypeDeclaration parentClass = TypeDeclaration.class.cast(method.getParent());
                    debug("Parent", parentClass.getName().toString());
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

public static void debug(String ref, String message) {
    System.out.println(ref + ": " + message);
}
```

With this code, the exact same thing happens, so I'm not quite sure whether I'm missing something or I found a bug.

As for *what* is happening, the `filter` method gets detected, as expected. However when accessing the parent, it becomes clear that the wrong parent was computed. This is, because `Locale` should be the parent's name, but it is `LanguageRange`.

**Output**

```
method: filter
Parent: LanguageRange
```

**Note** that it is assumed that the `java.util.Locale` class was used as input.

Did anyone experience this issue before? How would I go around it, in order to safely determine the parent of the method?

---

**UPDATE**

I tested some other classes as well and it seems they work just fine. Which makes it even more confusing.

Below is a sample taken from [Programm Creek](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/how-to-resolve-bindings-when-using-eclipse-jdt-astparser/), which I, again, altered to suit my needs.

**Sample**

```
package TEST;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IMethodBinding;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ITypeBinding;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IVariableBinding;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationFragment;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationStatement;

import app.configuration.Configuration;

public class ASTTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String srcPath = Configuration.app.getPaths().get("api") + "src"; // Absolute path to src folder
        String unitName = "Locale.java"; // Name of the file to parse
        String path = srcPath + "\\java\\util\\" + unitName; // Absoulte path to the file to parse
        File file = new File(path);

        String str = "";
        try {
            str = Files.lines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())).reduce((l1,  l2) -> l1 + System.lineSeparator() + l2).orElse("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

        parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);

        Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
        parser.setCompilerOptions(options);

        parser.setUnitName(unitName);

        String[] sources = { srcPath }; 
        String[] classpath = {"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_121\\lib\\rt.jar"}; // May need some altering

        parser.setEnvironment(classpath, sources, new String[] { "UTF-8"}, true);
        parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());

        CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        if (cu.getAST().hasBindingsRecovery()) {
            System.out.println("Binding activated.");
        }

        TypeFinderVisitor v = new TypeFinderVisitor();
        cu.accept(v);       
    }
}

class TypeFinderVisitor extends ASTVisitor{

    public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationStatement node){
        for (Iterator<?> iter = node.fragments().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println("------------------");

            VariableDeclarationFragment fragment = (VariableDeclarationFragment) iter.next();
            IVariableBinding binding = fragment.resolveBinding();

            System.out.println("binding variable declaration: " +binding.getVariableDeclaration());
            System.out.println("binding: " +binding);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration clazz){

        ITypeBinding binding = clazz.resolveBinding();
        if(binding != null){
            System.out.println("################ BINDING ##############");
            System.out.println(binding);
            System.out.println("##############################");
            for (IMethodBinding method : binding.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                System.out.println(clazz.getName().toString() + ": " + method.getName().toString());
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The output has a different format, but the result is the same.

**Result**

```
// Omitted...
LanguageRange: LanguageRange
LanguageRange: LanguageRange
LanguageRange: equals
LanguageRange: filter
LanguageRange: filter
LanguageRange: filterTags
LanguageRange: filterTags
LanguageRange: getRange
LanguageRange: getWeight
LanguageRange: hashCode
// Omitted...
```

However, when testing a smaller version of the exact same case, the result is correct.

**Example Class**

```
package TEST;

public class Test {
    public void methodBefore(){

    }

    public static class Inner{
        public static void foo(){

        }
    }

    public static class Inner2{
        public static void foo2(){

        }
    }

    public void methodAfter(){

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Test: Test
Test: methodAfter
Test: methodBefore
```

Since the example class `Test` is working, I assume that I'm missing something. But what?

**Note** that I use the AST parser *standalone* (i.e. I merely included the necessary libraries - which means I don't have access to classes like `IProject` and such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to my problem! I researched some more and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211511/6656268). While it does not seem to solve the OP's problem, it sure gave me an important hint.

I updated one of my classes accordingly (see below).

**Example**

```
package TEST;

import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration;

public class ASTBug {
    public static void parse(String code) {
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);

        Map<String, String> options = JavaCore.getOptions();
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_8);

        parser.setCompilerOptions(options);

        // Create a compilation unit
        parser.setSource(code.toCharArray());
        CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

            public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration clazz) {
                System.out.println("########### START ############");
                for (MethodDeclaration method : clazz.getMethods()) {
                    System.out.println(clazz.getName().toString() + ": " + method.getName().toString());
                }

                System.out.println("########### END ############");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Note** that now the options are set *properly*: `options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_8);`.

It makes sense, though. The default version is `JavaCore.Version_1_3` (as stated in the before-mentioned answer) and since `java.util.Locale` contains enums, which are supported starting with `JavaCore.VERSION_1_5` (again, stated in the before-mentioned answer) the parser gets screwed up. Or at least that's what I concluded from my inspections.

However, at first it still **did not work**. The solution was quickly found, but I'm not too certain about why this is necessary (see below). I used only **1** `ASTParser` instance, instead of **1 per file**, which seemed to somehow screw things up.

*In any case, it was not a bug, I just missed to properly set the options of the parser.*

Last but not least, have some class, which should work for `Java 8` and below.

**ASTCreator**

```
package ast;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;

public class ASTCreator{
    /**
     * The AST parser for parsing the Java files.
     */
    private ASTParser parser;
    /**
     * The compilation unit create through the AST parser.
     */
    private CompilationUnit compilationUnit;

    /**
     * Creates the parser with the specified setting.
     */
    private void create(){
        this.parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
        Map<String, String> options = JavaCore.getOptions();
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_8);
        this.parser.setCompilerOptions(options);
    }

    /**
     * Accepts the given visitors, which specify what to do with the parsed Java file.
     * @param fileContent the content of the file to parse
     * @param visitors the visitors to accept
     */
    public void accept(String fileContent, ASTVisitor... visitors){
        this.create();
        this.parser.setSource(fileContent.toCharArray());
        this.compilationUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        Arrays.stream(visitors).forEach(this.compilationUnit::accept);
    }
}
```

Create a new instance of this class (e.g. `astCreator`) and use it like this:
`astCreator.accept(fileReader.read(file), myVisitor);`. Obviousely, `fileReader` and `myVisitor` need to be replaced with your own code.